# Make efxclipse project build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, efxclipse

Right now I am setting up different projects from my company to work with Jenkins 1.645. But one project uses efxclipse and I didn't find any information how to connect these 2 things.

How can I build a e(fx)clipse project in Jenkins?

Comment: what type of efxclipse project is it? is it rcp(e4) Osgi based project? do you use `ant` or `maven-tycho` in jenkins build?

Comment: Since I have not created the efx project, I don't know - where can I see that? So far, we use only Ant builds in our Jenkins projects. No tycho has been used anywhere until now.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html install this in your eclipse and follow http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials  and then check out this awesome tutorial http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/. Hope this will help you in build activity of your application.